# Is there a multi-blog admin interface for WordPress blogs installed completely separately?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I'm an administrator of 10-20 separate WordPress blogs, and it's a big pain for me to login to all of them separately. Is there some sort of interface that allows me to do a single-sign-on administration of all of them, like there is under a [WordPress MU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress#Multi-blogging) umbrella?

If so, what's it called? I don't even know the term I'd use to search for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to try it, but [Virtual Multiblog](http://striderweb.com/nerdaphernalia/features/virtual-multiblog/) might solve your problem.

Or, try the search term:

> wordpress + multi blog

Google tends to vary results depending on your country of origin, so I'm not sure that what I found is what you'd find.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just managing posts & pages and a few other items, a blogging client might be the way to go. WordPress provides a good starter list of programs - http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client

Answer (score 0):

I've heard a lot of good things about http://managewp.com/

However I believe WordPress is implementing some sort of multi-blog support system in the next version release, so you may want to wait until that drops before laying out some cash for a service like ManageWP.